# fetched column value was truncated error in SQR File

Tags: oracle, sqr

We are having one SQR file.
When I execute that SQR,I got below error.

```
SQR 5528) ORACLE OCIStmtFetch error 1406 in cursor 1:
   ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated

Error on line 565:
   (SQR 3725) Bad return fetching row from database.
```

It usually runs well.
As far as I investigate I able to find in which SP it throws error.

But problem is that I couldn't find how to change select statement in SQR file to normal sql select statement which can be executed in Toad.
My SP has 3 select statement(union all).

Can anybody know what may be the cause of the issue.
It will be very helpful if anybody tell me the way to quickly change the select or how to run that SQR in toad.

Comment: You can add unions to SQR. You just have one Begin-Select block, and you put in the union as usual.  As far as what may be causing the error, check the field size on all fields in the union with their matching fields. I would need to see the code to help anymore than that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I  investigate further one of customer have '¿' this special character in name. Can this be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I investigate further one of customer have '¿' this special character in his name which is the reason for error.
After updating customer name report generated successfully.